Прикреплление видео в форму через яндекс дзен Wordpress
Есть ли какие-то плагины для прикрепллениея видео в форму через яндекс дзен как с ютуб или vimeo на Wordpress.

Гуглояндексы поломались?

Мне не вставить видео нужно, а функция загрузки видео от посетителей

Откуда это нам известно? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress
